# Vue router doesn't redirect to welcome page, if 404 page is defined with alias *

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have the following route configuration. I would expect the router to redirect the client to /dashboard when entering the page without any url extension. However, it displays the 404 page.  If I comment out `alias: '*'` for the 404 page (which technically disables it form my understanding), the redirect works as expected.

```js
function configRoutes() {
    return [
        {
            path: '/',
            redirect: '/dashboard',
            name: 'Home',
            component: TheContainer,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'dashboard',
                    name: 'Dashboard',
                    component: Dashboard
                },
                {
                    path: 'pickingList/:roleID-:roleName/:viewID-:viewName',
                    name: 'Kommissionierliste',
                    component: PickingList
                },
                {
                    path: 'admin/clients',
                    name: 'Clients',
                    component: AdminClients,
                    meta: {
                        requiresUserGroup: 'admin'
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: ':id-:name',
                            name: 'Clienteinstellungen',
                            component: AdminClientSettings,
                            meta: {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    path: 'admin/roles',
                    name: 'Rollen',
                    component: AdminRoles,
                    meta: {
                        requiresUserGroup: 'admin'
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: ':id-:name',
                            name: 'Rolleneinstellungen',
                            component: AdminRoleSettings,
                            meta: {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    path: 'login',
                    name: 'Login',
                    component: Login
                },
                {
                    path: 'admin/viewers',
                    name: 'Ansichten',
                    component: AdminViewerRoles,
                    meta: {
                        requiresUserGroup: 'admin'
                    },
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: ':id-:name',
                            name: 'Ansichtseinstellungen',
                            component: AdminViewerRoleSettings,
                            meta: {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    path: '404',
                    name: 'PageNotFound',
                    component: PageNotFound,
                    alias: '*',
                    meta: {
                        label: 'Seite nicht gefunden'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the 404 page up in the tree to be out of any `children` arrays, remove its alias and instead set its path to be `*`. The **catch-all** route should always be last in your list of routes (otherwise it will hide all routes which are listed after it in the array).

---

## Variant 1 - all routes are wrapped by TheContainer

App.vue

```
<template>
  <TheContainer>
    <MySidebar slot="sidebar" />
    <router-view />
  </TheContainer>
</template>
```

## Variant 2 - custom layout in each route

App.vue

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

Route A

```
<template>
  <LayoutA>
    <Sidebar slot="side" />
    <Toolbar slot="top" />
    <!-- content specific to the route -->
  </LayoutA>
</template>
```

Route B

```
<template>
  <LayoutY>
    <MyToolbar slot="top" />
    <!-- content for this route -->
    <MyFooter slot="bottom" />
  </LayoutY>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried that. The problem is, that the `TheContainer` object contains my layout. If I move it out of the child array, displaying the 404 page works fine, but without the page layout. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can create a higher-order component for the layout - a component which has SLOTs where you want to provide your content. Then in each page you will use the layout component and simply put your content in the slot(s). Or, you can put `TheContainer` inside your `App.vue` and use `<router-view>` inside the template for `TheContainer` where you want your routes to be rendered.

Comment: Would you please provide a simple, generic example how such a setup would look like?